# GCC/g++ cout << vs. printf()

Tags: c++, c, gcc, assembly, g++

- Why does `printf("hello world")` ends up using more CPU instructions in the assembled code (not considering the standard library used) than `cout << "hello world"`?

For C++ we have:

```
movl    $.LC0, %esi
movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
```

For C:

```
movl    $.LC0, %eax
movq    %rax, %rdi
movl    $0, %eax
call    printf
```

- WHAT are line 2 from the C++ code and lines 2,3 from the C code for?

I'm using gcc version 4.5.2

Comment: Why don't you compile a call to some of your own code (with inlining turned off) where you can see the source code/assembler relationship in both caller and callee.  Also, any time you're posted assembler, **you need to specify the architecture**.  Specifying the version of gcc would also be a good idea.

Comment: How would I turn it off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For 64bit gcc -O3 (4.5.0) on Linux x86_64, this reads for: **cout << "Hello World"**

```
movl    $11, %edx         ; String length in EDX
movl    $.LC0, %esi       ; String pointer in ESI
movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi  ; load virtual table entry of "cout" for "ostream"
call    _ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traits...basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l
```

and, for **printf("Hello World")**

```
movl    $.LC0, %edi       ; String pointer to EDI
xorl    %eax, %eax        ; clear EAX (maybe flag for printf=>no stack arguments)
call    printf
```

which means, your sequence depends entirely on any specific
compiler implementation, its version and probably compiler options.
**Your Edit** states,you use gcc 4.5.2 (which is fairly new).
Seems like 4.5.2 introduces additional 64bit register fiddling in
this sequence for whatever reason. It saves the 64bit RAX to RDI
before zeroing it out - which makes absolutely no sense (at least for me).

Much more interesting: 3 Argument call sequence (*g++ -O1 -S source.cpp*):

```
 void c_proc()
{
 printf("%s %s %s", "Hello", "World", "!") ;
}

 void cpp_proc()
{
 std::cout << "Hello " << "World " << "!";
}
```

leads to (**c_proc**):

```
movl    $.LC0, %ecx
movl    $.LC1, %edx
movl    $.LC2, %esi
movl    $.LC3, %edi
movl    $0, %eax
call    printf
```

with .LCx being the strings, and **no stack pointer involved**!

For **cpp_proc**:

```
movl    $6, %edx
movl    $.LC4, %esi
movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
call    _ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traits...basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l
movl    $6, %edx
movl    $.LC5, %esi
movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
call    _ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traits...basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l
movl    $1, %edx
movl    $.LC0, %esi
movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
call    _ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traits...basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l
```

You see now what this is all about.

Regards

rbo

Comment: *It saves the 64bit RAX to RDI before zeroing it out - which makes absolutely no sense (at least for me).* Actually it makes a lot of sense as %rdi is used as input parameter to printf function (see x64 ABI for details). Actually going through eax/rax makes little sense and probably means compilation without any optimizations.

Comment: @Tomek: I see your point. Bu what I mean is the following: If the string pointer is saved to EAX and then the whole RAX is coped over to RDI, **whats the point in this compared to copying the pointer directly to EDI** (as in my 4.5.0 example).

Comment: BTW, note that if you use normal optimization, it calls `std::__ostream_insert`, which needs a string length, but if you use `-Os`, it calls `std::operator<<`, w hich doesn't need the length (my guess it's inlining `operator<<` for non-Os cases).

Also a little nit: it's not loading the virtual table, it's just loading `std::cout` as the first argument to the stream function.

Answer (score 1):

The caller code is most of the time irrelevant to performance.

I guess the line 2 of the C++ code stores the address of std::cout as the implicit 'this'  argument of the operator<< method.

<strike>and i might be wrong on the C part, but it seems to me that it is incomplete. the 32bit upper part of rax is not initialized in this snippet, it might be initialized earlier.</strike> (no, i'm wrong here).

from what i understand (i might be wrong), the problem with 64bit registers, is that most of the time they cannot be initialized by immediates, so you have to play with 32bit operations to get the desired result. so the compiler plays with 32bit registers to initialize the 64bit rdi register.

And it seems that printf takes the value of al (the LSB of eax) as an input that tells printf() how many xmm 128 registers are used as input. It looks like an optimization to be able to pass the input string into the xmm registers or some other funny business.

Answer (score 1):

[`int printf( const char*, ...)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) is a variadic function that can take one or more arguments; whereas [`ostream& operator<< (ostream&, signed char*)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) takes exactly two.  I believe that that accounts for the difference in instructions needed to invoke them.

Line 2 in the C++ disassembly is where it passes the ostream&  (in this case `cout`). so the function knows what stream object it is outputting to.

Since both end up making a function call, the comparison is largely irrelevant; the code executed within the function call will be far more significant.  The operator<< is overloaded for a number of right-hand-side types, and is resolved at compile time; printf() on the other hand must parse the format string at runtime to determine the data type so may incur additional overhead.  Either way the amount of code executed within the functions will swamp the call overhead in terms of instructions executed, and will almost certainly be dominated by the OS code required to render the text on a graphical display.  So in short you are *sweating the small stuff*.

Comment: The difference can make sense in some circumstances, if we are optimizing for size instead of speed.

Comment: @junjanes: I was assuming that no optimisation was taking place in this case, but I an not sure what the comment has to do with this answer.  I would say that the difference is entirely because both functions involved have very different interfaces.  Just Apples & Oranges.

Answer (score 0):

movl is move long, 32-bit move

movq is move quad, 64-bit move

printf has a return value, either the number of characters written or -1 on failure, and that value is stored into %eax, that's all the extra line is worrying about.

Comment: I know what the instructions do, I am worrying WHY (what for) the code looks like it does. "movl    $0, %eax" means "move contant 0 into EAX", but WHY?

Comment: Probably, because printf is a variable argument function and needs a delimiter argument at the end.

Comment: I doubt that the extra code is anything to do with return value, since it is executed *before* the function call!  The function is responsible internally for setting its return value.  Moreover ostream::operator<<() returns an ostream& so the argument falls down in any case.  More likely that it is related to the number of variadic arguments.

Comment: it's just zeroing out that register, then its the number of parameter values

Comment: see my answer. eax is related to a possible optimization in printf(), as for the number of parameter values, i suggest it doesn't exist, because you can't retreive it on variadic functions of your own